# How to keep the check box and hold value in session after refresh page

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, codeigniter, checked

i am creating online exam system in php codeigniter, i am facing problem,  when i checked  multiple or one  answer and refresh the page checked answer will be not showing. please any one have solution for this code.

```
        <div class="checkbox checkbox-replace color-green">
          <input type="checkbox" id="chk_multi" onclick="return cheked_data()" 
             name="<?php echo $question['question_bank_id'].'[]'; ?>" 
             class="check_v" value="<?php echo $i + 1;?>">
          <label style="color: #373e4a; font-size: 15px;">
                <?php echo $options[$i];?>
          </label>
        </div>
   </div>
    <div class="col-md-6" style="margin-bottom: 15px; padding-right: 500px";>
                   
       <label class="container_radio">
           <div>
             <label style="color: #373e4a; font-size: 15px;">
                <?php echo get_phrase('true');?>
              </label>
          </div>
           <input type="radio" id="radio_true" class="check_v" onclick="return 
              cheked_data()" name="<?php echo 
              $question['question_bank_id'].'[]'; ?>" value="<?php echo $this- 
              >session- 
              >userdata($arraydata['radio_true']);?>" >
              <span class="checkmark"></span>
    </label>
    </div>
```

The script would be something like:

```
    $(function checked_data() {
     var chk_multi = $("input#chk_multi").val();
     var chk_img = $("input#chk_image").val();
     var radio_true = $("input#radio_true").val();
     var radio_false = $("input#radio_false").val();
     var fill_blank = $("input#fill_blank").val();
     var data = { 'services[]' : []};
      $("input:checked").each(function() {
      data['services[]'].push($(this).val()); 
     }); 
    $.ajax({
         type:'POST',
         url:'<?php echo base_url();?>student/hold_checked/'+$online_exam_id,
         data: {chk_multi: chk_multi,chk_img: chk_img,radio_true: radio_true,
                radio_false: radio_false,fill_blank: fill_blank}
         success: function(data){
           $('#chk_multi').html(data);
           $('#chk_image').html(data);
           $('#radio_false').html(data);
           $('#radio_true').html(data);
           $('#fill_blank').html(data);
         }
     });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: you can use the `checked` attribute for that purpose

Answer (score 0):

You can Save the value of the checkbox into localStorage I think your question is similar to this [check the link below]
[localStorage how to save a checkbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26628812/localstorage-how-to-save-a-checkbox)